# JQuery Hide after append

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, append, hide

I am running a script that will append an element upon selecting it from a dropdown list, that bit all works fine and appends the item. The item appended includes a button that will hide the appended item when clicked. What I can't seem to get to work is the hide function. The code seems to work fine if I put the element in manually into the HTML and click the hide button but for some reason when appending it it doesn't work?

```
$('#addteammember').click(function() {
 var usernamevalue = $("#teammemberselected").val();
 var teammemberfullname = $('#teammemberselected option:selected').text();
  $('#teammemberlist').append("<li><input class='removeteam' type='button' value="+usernamevalue+" /><span class='listitem'>"+teammemberfullname+"</span></li>");
});


$('.removeteam').click(function () {
  $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It happens because you append the button dynamically but bind your `click` handler for already existing elements only. You can use this code instead:

```
$("#teammemberlist").on("click", ".removeteam", function () {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the `on` method was introduced in jQuery version 1.7. If for some reason you have to work with an older version, try [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/). I recommend `delegate` over `live` for performance reasons. I'm not sure how `on` stacks up to these two methods.

Answer (score 0):

Try `live` function.

```
$(".removeteam").live("click", function() {
$(this).hide();
});
```